# Issue with onLongClickListener and Position

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

So I have a listview full of cards and I want to longPress each one and be able to share the text that is on the card. I've done research about longPress events and this is what I came up with:

Setting listener on listview

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        showOptionsMenu(position);
        return false;
    }
});
```

And here is the showOptionsMenu method

```
public void showOptionsMenu(int position) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCancelable(true).setItems(R.array.longClickItems,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                TextView tvMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
                TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

                String message = tvMessage.getText().toString();
                String name = tvName.getText().toString();

                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "Message:\n" + message + "\n" + "\nSigned by:\n" + name;
                shareBody = shareBody.replace("-", "");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send To:"));
            }
        }).show();
}
```

Now, all this works great except there's one problem: every time I long press, no matter the list item position, the text retrieved is always from the first item in the list. I tried some of the getPosition methods in the listview class but nothing worked...help is appreciated!

Comment: return false; what is this

Comment: Which xml has `tvContent` and `tTitle`  ?

Comment: **Plus** you pass `position` in function `showOptionsMenu`, but don't use that. Please correct your logic. Initialize textview based on position and retrieve text accordingly.

Comment: Please Use The Position in Function showOptionsMenu(position);

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the input `position` in `showOptionsMenu(int position)`.

In the OnLongClick, the parameters are:

```
parent       The AbsListView where the click happened
view         The view within the AbsListView that was clicked
position     The position of the view in the list
id           The row id of the item that was clicked
```

You can use the:

> parent.getItemAtPosition(position)

to obtain the item at that position. Then you can pass that item to your other method or perhaps Toast the card name.

Or directly use the `view` parameter which is the view that was clicked and then display what you want.

Comment: getItemAtPosition returns an object thus making it not compatible with the int param in my method  ??

Comment: Well you need to convert or cast that Object to what you need. You should also change your showOptionsMenu method because right now it is not using it's input at all. My explanation shows you how to get the item clicked. You decide what to do with it :)

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "right now it is not using it's input at all". I'm giving the method an int called position. For lack of better naming, the method param is an int called position as well. Perhaps it's just something I'm forgetting from my knowledge of Java.

Comment: The parameter int position inside the function showOptionsMenu isn't used anywhere. You just pass it in but you don't use it.

Comment: Ooooohhhh! Now I get what you mean...yeah it was a brain fart. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Well this didn't really answer my question. I merely gave me a new mindset. I did upvote it though.

Answer (score 1):

You should call [`getItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)) on the adapter and pass the object(that is, the data at `position` of the data array ) to `showOptionsMenu`